# Multiple string replacements with a list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use a list remove multiple items from a single text string.

This is a start to the solution:

```
tmp_text = 'Mr. Random Name'
replace = ['Mr. ', 'Ms. ','Prof. ']
tmp_text = [tmp_text.replace(r, '') for r in replace]
```

However, I want to return a single text string which has all of the items in the list "replace" removed from it.  The above return three strings:
['Random Name', 'Mr. Random Name', 'Mr. Random Name']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go -

```
tmp_text = 'Mr. Random Name'

replace = ['Mr. ', 'Ms. ','Prof. ' ]
for i in replace :
    tmp_text = tmp_text.replace(i, '')
```

Answer (score 3):

Either replace in a loop:

```
for r in replace:
    tmp_text = tmp_text.replace(r, "")
```

Or use regular expressions:

```
tmp_text = re.sub("|".join(replace), "", tmp_text)
```

Comment: I was trying to do it as an inline function but the loop does the trick :) Thanks.